# Como fazer While de uma tabela e mostrar dados de outra?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho duas tabelas:

```
Tabela1: 
 Id int A_I;
 Modelo varchar;

Tabela2:
 Id int A_I;
 Id_fk int (foreign key da tabela1);
 cor;
```

E queria fazer um while da tabela1 mas mostrar os dados da tabela2.

```html
<?php
 include 'conn.php';
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
   
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tabela1");
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tabela2");
   
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Como é que faço agora para mostrar os dados?

Comment: Eu sei que não pede por isto e é por isso que isso que não vou responder em baixo, pois pode não querer mesmo isto. Mas porque não faz join das duas tabelas: `SELECT * FROM Tabela1 JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela1.id = Tabela2.Id_fk;`

Comment: E depois como vou buscar os dados à tabela2? basta no while $cor = $row['cor']; ?

Comment: Sim em princípio será... Tem nomes de colunas iguais?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução que deixei em comentário seria a mais indicada:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela1 JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela1.id = Tabela2.Id_fk;
```

Mas para haver coerência entre resposta/pergunta aqui fica uma solução para o que pediu:

**No caso de a tabela2 só poder ter uma linha com o mesmo Id_fk:**

```
$selTab1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabela1;");
$dataJoin = array();
while ($rowTab1 = $selTab1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $selTab2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabela2 where Id_fk={$rowTab1['id']};");
    if($selTab2->num_rows > 0) {
        $rowTab2 = $selTab2->fetch_assoc();
        $dataJoin[] = array(
            'tab1_id' => $rowTab1['id'],
            'Modelo' => $rowTab1['Modelo'],
            'tab2_id' => $rowTab2['id'],
            'cor' => $rowTab2['cor']
        );
    }
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($dataJoin), '</pre>'; // aqui já vai ter os dados das duas
```

**No caso de a tabela2 poder ter mais do que uma linha com o mesmo Id_fk:**

```
$selTab1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabela1;");
$dataJoin = array();
while ($rowTab1 = $selTab1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $selTab2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabela2 where Id_fk={$rowTab1['id']};");
    while($rowTab2 = $selTab2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataJoin[] = array(
            'tab1_id' => $rowTab1['id'],
            'Modelo' => $rowTab1['Modelo'],
            'tab2_id' => $rowTab2['id'],
            'cor' => $rowTab2['cor']
        );
    }
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($dataJoin), '</pre>'; // aqui já vai ter os dados das duas
```